# How to link from a HTML 5 canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to create links from an HTML 5 canvas animation. How can I make a specific image in the canvas also a link?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't put links on a canvas as such; a canvas is canvas, not a document. What you can do is overlay image maps or invisible elements, or handle clicks using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canvas tag doesn't have link functionality, however you might be able to use javascript coding to manually link to a new page. Just add an onclick event that fires the link.

Also, the canvas won't know where your image is. So if the image is only taking up part of the canvas, you will need to check the mouse position to make sure the image is being clicked directly.